# Django storages using incorrect urls for s3 static files

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage, python-django-storages

I am using Django storages to host my static files (css, js, images) on s3. When I load my webpage django keeps pointing to the incorrect url of my s3 public bucket. For example, it keeps returning `https://mysite.amazonaws.com/assets/images/cat.png` despite the correct public url for the file being `https://mysite.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/assets/images/cat.png`

settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('aws_access_key_id')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('aws_secret_key')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mysite'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = "private"
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-southeast-2'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_URL = 'https://mysite.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a s3 custom domain.

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'mysite.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'
```